# Building a XPages App with Maven and running Junit Tests

Tags: maven, xpages, junit4, lotus-domino, maven-surefire-plugin

I have an Domino XPages Application which is already built from an OnDiskProject into an .nsf by maven.
The pom.xml for that step is ok and running.
Now, I wanted to include the maven-surefire-plugin (or any other) to execute the Junit Tests. But maven told me, that there are no tests found.
I use the Packaging Type domino-nsf from frostillic.us, which works fine for compiling and deploying.
The plugin definition is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
              <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
              <version>2.8</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>test</id>
           <phase>test</phase>
           <configuration>
             <includes>
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
              </includes>
           </configuration>
           <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
 </plugin>
```

We use the https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/org.openntf.junit.xsp plugin to develop tests. The tests are running in the browser with no problem (calling an Xpage with Junit tests).

May be I have to create a separate module for testing, but I did not have success with that approach. Any help or hints are appreciated and welcome.

I tried it with the maven-surefire-plugin and also with tycho-surefire-plugin. But both didn't work. The tycho-surefire-plugin don't work with the domino-nsf packaging type.

Update:

Here is the complete pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <groupId>TMS</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>domino-nsf</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <bazaar-version>2.0.9</bazaar-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactory.openntf.org</id>
            <name>artifactory.openntf.org</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.openntf.org/openntf</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>artifactory.openntf.org</id>
            <name>artifactory.openntf.org</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.openntf.org/openntf</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openntf.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>nsfodp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compiletests</id>
                        <phase>test-compile-plugin</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <updateSites>
                        <updateSite>C:\Users\xxx\Documents\junit\org.openntf.junit.xsp.updatesite</updateSite>
                    </updateSites>
                    <binaryDxl>true</binaryDxl>
                    <propertiesEncoding>UTF-8</propertiesEncoding>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <templateName>TMS</templateName>
                    <deployDestPath>127.0.0.1!!xxx\xxx.nsf</deployDestPath>
                    <deployReplaceDesign>true</deployReplaceDesign>
                    <acl>
                        <roles>
                            <role>[_Admins]</role>
                        </roles>
                        <entries>
                            <entry>
                                <name>-Default-</name>
                                <defaultEntry>true</defaultEntry>
                                <level>noaccess</level>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <name>[OtherDomainServers]</name>
                                <level>noaccess</level>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <name>[LocalDomainAdmins]</name>
                                <level>manager</level>
                                <deleteDocs>true</deleteDocs>
                                <noReplicate>false</noReplicate>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <name>[LocalDomainServers]</name>
                                <level>manager</level>
                                <deleteDocs>true</deleteDocs>
                                <noReplicate>false</noReplicate>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <name>CN=xxx/O=xxx</name>
                                <level>manager</level>
                                <deleteDocs>true</deleteDocs>
                                <noReplicate>false</noReplicate>
                                <roles>
                                    <role>[_Admins]</role>
                                </roles>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <name>CN=Administrator/O=xxx</name>
                                <level>manager</level>
                                <deleteDocs>true</deleteDocs>
                                <noReplicate>false</noReplicate>
                                <roles>
                                    <role>[_Admins]</role>
                                </roles>
                            </entry>
                        </entries>
                    </acl>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[Output Maven Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtSvK.png)

[Directory Structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBIW6.png)

[ODP Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIQb9.png)

Comment: Really use such ancient version of surefireplugin the include give the default so no need to configure that... also binding it manually to the life cycle ? No...plase show more information if wrote `does not work` what does that mean? Error ? Nothing is being executed? Log output ? Test example ? Which testing framework do you use? How have you called Maven? Tycho Project??

Comment: You might need to include path information in your includes. Can you update your question with a screenshot of your directory layout?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I updated my question with more information.